# Dynamically generated CSS Angular 4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to add custom generated CSS (built from access to a database) and have it appear in the page, using Angular 4.

So far I have tried creating a component and adding it to other components (HTML files) but it appears to not be showing anything on the page, nor is it changing anything. I have also looked into adding additional CSS to each component but that will be a management nightmare for changes.

I know I could create multiple themes, or just add another class to a HTML tag. There are no themes in the system I am building and we need to have it so the user can define the styling, using any color, etc of their choosing.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: where is the custom generated css stored? if you're using angular-cli, why not pack it into a css file and list it in styles section at .angular-cli.config?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create css class for whole document with angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868608/create-css-class-for-whole-document-with-angular)